# Flutter when ListView.builder is refreshed it goes back from the beggining and not from the maxScrollExtent point

Tags: flutter

I am new in Flutter and I am facing a problem.

What I have so far is that I am getting the data from a web service asynchronously (Json). So in the build method I use a `FutureBuilder` widget for Scaffold's body argument. And its 'builder' argument (of `FutureBuilder` widget) returns a `ListView.builder` to show the data.
Also I use `ScrollController` for scrolling.

Its time I reach the maximum scroll point I call once again the service to get the next page of data and so on...

The problem is that when I "change page" by scrolling it brings the data correctly, but it starts from the very first line of data and not from the point where i ve reached the `maxScrollExtent` point.

So if the first 'snapshot' has 25 rows and the second has 15, when I go to the second it starts from row 1 and not from row 26 although the total amount of data row is 40 correctly .

As a result i don't have a smooth scrolling. I have been stuck for enough time to this point and i do not know what I am missing. Do I have to use Page Storage keys (i saw video from flutter team but i haven't found an edge to my problem). Any hints? A sample of code follows.

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  
  final ScrollController _controller = ScrollController();
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller.addListener(_scrollListener);
  }
  void _scrollListener() {
    if (_controller.offset >= _controller.position.maxScrollExtent &&
        !_controller.position.outOfRange) {

      if (nextDataSet != null) {
        print('nextDataSet = ' + nextDataSet);
        setState(() {
          inDataSet = nextDataSet;
        });
      } else {
        print('nextDataSet = NULL');
      }

  }

  Future<Post> fetchPost([String dataSet]) async {
  ...
  return Post.fromJson(json.decode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes)));
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Builder(
        builder: (context) => Scaffold(
        ...
        body: FutureBuilder<Post>(
                  future: fetchPost(inDataSet),
                  builder: _buildList,
                ),
        ),
      ),
    );
    }

  Widget _buildList(BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
     ... /*code that eventually fills the lists of strings 
         progressivePartyListSec, progressivePartyListThird*/
     ...
     return ListData(controller: _controller, listEidosPerigr: 
     progressivePartyListSec, listPerigr: progressivePartyListThird );
  }

}

class ListData extends StatelessWidget {

  final ScrollController controller;
  final List<String> listEidosPerigr;
  final List<String> listPerigr;

  ListData({this.controller,
    this.listEidosPerigr,
    this.listPerigr});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return ListView.builder(
        controller: controller,
        itemCount: rowsSelected,
        itemBuilder: (context, i) {
          return Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  removeAllHtmlTags(listEidosPerigr[i]),
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.blue),
                ),
                new RichText(
                  text: new TextSpan(
                      text: listPerigr[i].replaceAllMapped('<BR>', (Match m) => '').replaceAllMapped('<b>', (Match m) => '').replaceAllMapped('</b>', (Match m) => ''),
                      style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style,
                  ),
                ),
              ]);
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: Would you mind to add more code

Comment: Yes of course, i've added the related code...

Answer (score 1):

after some research i found a solution in the following link: [Flutter: Creating a ListView that loads one page at a time](https://medium.com/saugo360/flutter-creating-a-listview-that-loads-one-page-at-a-time-c5c91b6fabd3)

Thanks a lot AbdulRahman AlHamali.

Basically, on the above code that i have posted, i used another argument for the ListView.builder and it is the following ***key: PageStorageKey('offset'),***

Finally as AbdulRahman writes on his article i used the KeepAliveFutureBuilder as a wrapper of FutureBuilder in other worlds in my build method i did...

```
body: KeepAliveFutureBuilder(
            //child: FutureBuilder<Post>(
                future: fetchPost(inDataSet),
                builder: _buildList,
              //),
          ),
```